# jEditable - how do I get the edited textfield variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-plugins

I have a table that I use jEditable with.

Saving to the server works, but the callback for refreshing my table element (that I just edited and saved to the server) does *not* work.

```
    /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
$('#example tbody td').editable( '<%= url_for :controller => 'impact_matrix', :action => 'post', :scenario => params[:id] %>', {
  "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
                          ^ goes missing
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
    oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
  },
  "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
    temp = value
    return { "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id') };
  },
```

sValue (that I point to in the code) - seems to be blank.

I do get values for aPos[0] and aPos[1], but not sValue.

Could someone please explain to me 'what triggers the callback function?'

Or, if I could just see where to get the 'newly edited text' and then just run fnUpdate() on that, I'd be fine.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: On the website they refer to 

user_edited_content

as the variable that gets passed as the value.

I do get the following string sent to server:
Parameters: {"row_id"=>"2", "action"=>"post", "id"=>"0", "value"=>"444", "controller"=>"impact", "scenario_setting"=>"1"}

Where value = 444 or whatever I edited last.

I think this might be a scope problem for me. Where does user_edit_content reside?

Comment: Can you add an example on jsFiddle?